# Seeking school boundaries?

Tags: data, administrative-boundaries, boundaries

I have seen [Where to get school zone shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74030) which seems to be the closest to my need.

When I download the docs, either I have no ways to filter the document or I don't see all the schools. I have been trying for a week now.

I can download individual files [here](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_sd.html), but it definitely does not have all schools.

Where can I obtain all school boundaries (starting with CA)?

---

As I wrote in the very first paragraph, there is a question very similar to this one, but it does not answer my question for two reasons:

1. the Census offers School District and also some Elementary School boundaries, but they are not accurate down to each individual school.
2. I downloaded a huge file from that question, but it has no description (some generic name for each file), it is for the whole country, and I don't have any software that allows me to see the file. I need to click on every school in the country until I find my local school, and chances are these two sources are actually just one, and it will not have the individual elementary, middle and high school.

Image 1 is the city school district boundaries (which I also need, so that is helpftul).

[image]

Image 2 has some Elementary schools, not for all cities, and most importantly, it does not match reality. Each city has many elementary schools, and the map brings just one for "some" cities.

[image]

Comment: If it is open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thank you, @PolyGeo. I didn't know that group, and they also have some similar questions.
They bumped into the same problem as myself. 
https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11112/is-there-a-way-to-get-us-public-school-serving-area

Comment: @ianTurton, you said this is a duplicate of another question. Can you please, based on the other question/answer, post here a link for the boundary of any elementary school in the country? Or middle school? Yes, you will find some HS because quite often it will match the district boundary. 
You said it's answered, so it will be very easy. 
Thank you.

Comment: The answer is that it is not available during the shutdown. Just because you don't like the answer does not make it wrong.

Comment: I didn't make it wrong. It does not answer my question that you blocked. Do you know the difference between school district and school?

Comment: @IanTurton, I guess you are the owner of the stackexchange. I am telling the other answer is incomplete, and you keep this off the public to answer. Gosh, be happy! I will post this question again.

Comment: If enough people agree with you the question will be reopened otherwise your next question will be closed as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: And how many people agreed that this question is answered elsewhere?